# approximate solution of linear nonhomogeneous differential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have following differential equation:
$$
x''(t) + a x'(t) + b x(t) = c u''(t) + d u'(t) + e u(t)\ \ \ \ \ (\star)
$$
with zero initial conditions $x(0) = 0$, $x'(0) = 0$, $a,b,c,d,e$ -- some constants. Function $u(t)$ is a known function - Heaviside function:
$$
u(t) = 
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
0,\ \ t<0\\
1,\ \ t\geq 0
\end{array}
\right .
$$
I would like to find approximate solution of this equation in the following way.

Instead of $u(t)$ I put to the equation $(\star)$ its continuous up to first derivative approximation $(n=1,2,\ldots)$:
$$
u_n(t) = 
\left \{
\begin{array}{l}
0,\ \ t<0\\
3n^2t^2-2n^3t^3,\ \ 0\leq t < \frac 1n\\
1,\ \ t\geq \frac 1n
\end{array}
\right .
$$

Of course $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}u_n(t) = u(t)$ in some space.

My question: If $x(t)$ is a solution of $(\star)$ and $x_n(t)$ is a solution of $(\star)$ if I instead of $u(t)$ put $u_n(t)$, then are there any theorems that guarantee convergence:  $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n(t) = x(t)$?